# Samba share not working with Windows10

Tags: samba

I am trying establish connection between Samba server and Windows10 with no luck. Secured share between: **samba server > Ubuntu 16.04** & **samba server > Windows7** works fine, but not Windows10.

Here is the config file:

```
[global]

workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = ubuntu
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no

[secured]
 path = /samba/secured
 valid users = @smbgrp
 guest ok = no
 writable = yes
 browsable = yes
```

If I try to establish from W10 `\\my-ip-goes-here` nothing happens. I tried to turn off firewall, defender even another PC with W10. Any ideas?

P.S extra troubleshooter from W10 machine:

[w10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ybeh.png)

Comment: I think this problem comes from Windows 10 and its Credential Manager.  You can try next solution. Go to: `Windows 10` > `Control Panel` > `User Accounts` > `Credential Manager` (or just type "credential" in the search bar) > `Windows Credentials`. Find and **Remove** Windows Credentials for your samba share. Try to browse again.

Comment: The problem still exist :(

Comment: Allow next ports on Ubuntu Firewall: 445, 137, 138, 139.